# Error while installing RSAT (Remote SysAdmin Tools for Windows 7 with SP1)

Tags: windows-7, administration

I have Windows 7 SP1 32bit, and I can't install RSAT (Remote SysAdmin Tools for Windows 7 with SP1) x86.

I'm getting error `0x80070442` each time.

It's saying that the specified service can't be started because all the corresponding devices turned off.

What does it mean? (I translated the error message from Russian to English so it's not 100% equal.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out! It was because the Windows Update service was turned off and RSAT is installed as Windows Update.